# Multiple rows.Next() in the same time golang sql/database

Tags: mysql, go, struct, slice

I am working on a function which gets users. My problem is that I have to return the result of two queries as one result in the `rows.Next()` and `rows1.Next()` like `user_id`, `subject`, `phone`.

Here is what I have but it doesn't work. Could you please help me out with some suggestions:

```
func GetUsers() (users []Users, err error) {

    users = make([]Users, 0)
    rows, err := db1.Query("SELECT  user_id, subject,phone FROM users limit 11")
    rows1, err := db1.Query("Select body from users limit 11")
    defer rows.Close()
    if err != nil {
        // handle this error better than this
        log.Fatal(err)
        //return
    }
    var user Users
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&user.ID, &user.Subject, &user.Phone)
        users = append(users, user)
    }
    for rows1.Next() {

        rows1.Scan(&user.Body)
        users = append(users, user)

    }
    return 
}
```

I have a table called `users` which has no primary key, basically:

```
user_id . name  . body 
-----------------------
1       . model . 2
1       . brand . 1
1       . fuel  . 3
1       . date  . 1
1       . year  . 1
```

I have to have a result:

```
userid . model . brand . fuel . date . year 
1      . 2     . 1     . 3    . 1    . 1
```

so the values in the column name gonna be as rows. I have already defined my struct which contains all the fields needed.

Comment: Can you expand on "it doesn't work"? What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: How do you know that the `body` you are returning in your second query is going to correspond with the `user_id` from the first query? Why not just retrieve `body` in the first query. It's a little weird what you are doing and seems like it would lead to lots of oddball issues.

Comment: my problem that i have to merge the the rows.Next() as query1 getting id,subject,phone  with the rows1.Next()getting just body  to get  one result having all fields i hope it's clear mr @Adrian thanks

Comment: @Medone you're querying the same table in both queries, just do it in one query and your problem is solved.

Comment: It's not at all clear why though. Just add `body` into your first query. It's coming from the same table so the relationship for the user already exists. then add all four attributes to `users.user` at once.

Comment: Your other option, which would be crazy bananas, would be to run your second query INSIDE the `for` loop reading your first queries result, grabbing the body for the user that you are reading/building. But please don't do that.

Comment: I see what you mean mr JNevill . it will be easy to applicate your point of view but it isn't my case , i must get the same result as i described for my tables issue

Comment: So you are going to select 11 users. Then you are going to select, randomly, 11 bodys from 11 other users. Then you are going to build `users.user` using the first person from query1 and the first, random, body from query2. Then go onto the second user from query and the second ranomd body from query2. It sounds to me like you are making some bad assumptions here. I feel like they "Why" is missing here. What are you REALLY trying to do, because what you are doing doesn't make any sense and probably doesn't do what you think it will.

Comment: i edited my problem hope that is understooded thanks mr @JNevill

Comment: @Medone If you have a table without a primary key you're almost certainly doing it wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looking at the example code it's clear that you should do whatever you're doing in one query instead of two. Even if your real code is a little different, say you need to query more than one table, you should still probably do only one query using JOINs.

```
users := make([]*User, 0)
rows, err := db1.Query("SELECT  user_id, subject,phone, body FROM users limit 11")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    user := new(User)
    if err := rows.Scan(&user.ID, &user.Subject, &user.Phone, &user.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }       
    users = append(users, user)
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

That said, if you want to do it the way you illustrated in your question you can do that like this.

*(this probably not what you should do)*

```
users := make([]*User, 0)
rows, err := db1.Query("SELECT  user_id, subject,phone FROM users limit 11")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer rows.Close()

rows1, err := db1.Query("Select body from users limit 11")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer rows1.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    user := new(User)
    if err := rows.Scan(&user.ID, &user.Subject, &user.Phone); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if !rows1.Next() {
        panic("no next body row")
    }
    if err := rows1.Scan(&user.Body); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    users = append(users, user)
}
if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if err := rows1.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mkopriva this is waht i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

```
const maxPerPage = 100

type Scanable interface {
    GetScans() []interface{}
}

type User struct {
    ID      int
    Subject string
    Phone   string
    Body    string
}

func (s *User) GetScans() []interface{} {
    return []interface{}{&s.ID, &s.Subject, &s.Phone, &s.Body}
}

func getNewUserList() []*User {
    users := make([]*User, maxPerPage)
    for i := 0; i < maxPerPage; i++ {
        users[i] = new(User)
    }
    return users
}

var usersPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() interface{} {
        return getNewUserList()
    },
}

func getUsers() (b []*User) {
    ifc := usersPool.Get()
    if ifc != nil {
        b = ifc.([]*User)
    } else {
        b = getNewUserList()
    }
    return
}

func putUsers(b []*User) {
    // if cap(b) <= maxPerPage {
    //     b = b[:0] // reset
    //     usersPool.Put(&b)
    // }
    usersPool.Put(&b)
}

func TestUsers(t *testing.T) {

    users := getUsers()

    rows, err := PostgresConnection.Query("SELECT user_id, subject,phone, body FROM users limit 11")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    length := 0
    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(users[i].GetScans()...); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            if err := rows.Err(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        length++
    }

    result := users[:length]
    fmt.Println(result)

    putUsers(users)
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is the sample function to get multiple document from db using golang sqlx library.

```
func GetDocuments() ([]SupportedDocument, error) {
    var documents []SupportedDocument
    query := `SELECT * FROM documents limit 10`
    err := database.Select(&documents, query)
    return documents, err
}
```